# Local cohomology: Polynomial ring vs Power series ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

I study algebraic topology and am currently examining the applications of local (co)homology in algebraic topology. We have the canonical inclusion of rings $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\subset \mathbb{Z}[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$. Define $\mathfrak{m}_1=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\subset \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Is there any relation between the local cohomology modules $H^i_{\mathfrak{m}_1}(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n])$ and $H^i_{\mathfrak{m}_2}(\mathbb{Z}[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]])$ when considered as modules over $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$?

Comment: Maybe this questions is a bit vague/open-ended, but (disclaimer: not knowing anything about local cohomology) it seems okay to me so I wonder why it was down-voted.

Comment: I think that for any flat ring map $R \to S$ and $R$-module $M$, $H^i_{\mathfrak{m}}(M) \otimes_R S = H^i_{\mathfrak{m}S}(M \otimes_R S)$.  In your case, the inclusion into the completion is flat since $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @SamHopkins Maybe it was voted down because one of the very first examples of local cohomology you would compute if you learned about it would be these.